# AutoSuggest field2 based on field1 selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

JS is still a little unnatural to me. I can read it *alright*, but writing it is something I seldom get the chance to do.

I have this form (simplified)

```
<form>
    <div class="form_element">
        <label for="co">Cust Company:</label>    
        <input type="text" name="co" value="" id="co" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_element">
        <label for="contact">Cust Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="contact" value="" id="contact" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I got the auto-complete working just fine for the `#co` input, but I can use a little guidance getting the next step working.
I need to auto-suggest Names for the `#contact` input based on the `#co` selection.

My JS currently looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input#co').autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response1 ) {
            url_1 = 'company/get_names/'+ request.term +'/name/json'
            $.getJSON(url_1, function(companies) {
                response1(companies);
            });
        },
        select: function(event, company){
            $('input#co' ).val( company.item.value );

            //alert(company.item.id);   // For testing
            url_2 = 'contact/persons_list/'+ company.item.id +'/json'

            $('input#contact').autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response2 ) {
                    $.getJSON(url_2, function(people) {  
                        response2(people);
                    });
                }
            })
        }    
    });
</script>
```

How do I get the suggestion-list of people/contacts to show up for the `#contact` input once a value/suggestion is selected for the `#co` input?

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I ended up taking a completely different approach, and I think it's ***much*** better than my first line of thought.

```
<script type="text/javascript">      

    var co_id;

    $('input#co').autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            url = 'company/get_names/'+ request.term +'/name/json',
            $.getJSON(url, function(companies) {
                response(companies);
            });
        },
        select: function(event, company){
            $('input#co' ).val( company.item.value );
            co_id = company.item.id;
        }
    });

    $('input#contact').autocomplete({
        //minLength: 2,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            url = 'contact/persons_list/'+co_id+'/json',
            $.getJSON(url, function(companies) {
                response(companies);
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

It works great!